# How Can I get the recycleBin Path for each disk, for different operation System?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, path, recycle-bin

WinXP, Vista, Win7, there is a certain folder for recyclebin.

How Can I get the recycleBin Path for each disk, for different operation System?

in WinXP it is called XX:\RECYCLER, while in vista it used another name.

Is there any windows C++ API for it ?

Many thanks!

Comment: What are you planning to do with it? You can't treat the contents as regular files.

Answer (score 3):

You can ask a shell namespace object for its [SHDESCRIPTIONID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/ns-shlobj_core-shdescriptionid) and compare with the CLSID of the recycle bin, see [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080918-00/?p=20843) for more info.